# Angular Bootstrap Datepicker Keep Selected Date on Arrow Navigation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap

When you navigate from month to month using the datepicker, it makes the first day of the month active. The only active date I want, is the initial one or the one I click on like seen here http://jsfiddle.net/the_menace/ddvg5wg1/
Looking in the ui-bootstrap-tpls.js file i found the $scope.move function that set's the first day of each mont as active with this line of code 
`self.activeDate.setFullYear(year, month, 1);`

When I remove the 1, a random date is set to default. How can I have the highlighted date to only be he initial one or the one I click on?

Comment: I have the same issue too.

Comment: Any update on this issue? I face the same problem...

Comment: yo what's up 2018 and having the same problem